# integrate partial area under curve in R

Tags: r, partial, auc

I've fit a gaussian curve to the below data, and I would like to calculate the area under the curve between certain values of x (e.g., from x=6 to x=18). The below code produces the following error: "Error in f(x, c(m, s, a, b)) : unused argument (c(m, s, a, b))". Also, I have a few negative values and need to subtract the negative area from the positive because I'm interested in the 'net' value.

```
x <- c(12.88, 12.9, 8.35, 10.52, 10.45, 8.44, 9.01, 9.96, 9.82, 9.83, 10.65, 10.69, 15.3, 15.33, 12.41, 12.43, 8.36, 8.43, 9.29, 9.25, 14.78, 14.87, 16.17, 16.23, 3.59, 4.37, 3.88, 19.88, 20.71, 20.33, 21.25, 22.09)
y<-c(10.8, 9.62, 11.76, 5.12, 9.63, 4.80, 11.09, 7.42, 7.79, 9.76, 9.71, 8.13, 14.4, 14.85, 12.84, 11.59, 7.0, 6.49, 5.94, 4.93, 6.43, 7.8, 3.81, 2.6, -0.93, 5.3, 1.08, 0.39, -0.59, 2.77, 3.5, -2.08)
df<-data.frame(x, y)

#Define a Gaussian function (Y=Amplitude*exp(-0.5*((X-Mean)/SD)^2) + Baseline)
f<-function(x, theta) {
   m<-theta[1]; s<-theta[2]; a<-theta[3]; b<-theta[4];
   a*exp(-0.5*((x-m)/s)^2) + b
}

fit<-nls(y~f(x,c(m,s,a,b)), data.frame(x,y), start=list(m=12, s=5, a=12,  b=-2)) 
xs<-seq(0,24,l=1000)
f<-function(x) predict(fit,newdata=data.frame(x=xs))
integrate(f,6,18)
```

Comment: @BondedDust, I know how to build dataframes and 'take babysteps' in R.... I changed the formatting of my question to demonstrate that....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in variables `TimeOfDay` and `y`, this should work (I am assuming loess curve will work for your needs. You may (will) need to change the model you are fitting based on your data. Depending on the model, your integrand will change and so will your result!!)

```
df <- data.frame(TimeOfDay,y)
df <- df[order(df$TimeOfDay),]
l <- loess(y ~ TimeOfDay, df, control=loess.control(surface="direct"))
f <- function(x) predict(l,newdata = x)

integrate(f,2,3) #you can specify between what times you want to integrate here

plot(df)
lines(l)
```

[image: the plot resulting from your data]

Comment: I've followed your code but using a gaussian fit instead of loess (updated code above), but I'm getting errors when I try to integrate (error copy/pasted in updated question above).

Answer (score 0):

```
> fit
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ f(x, c(m, s, a, b))
   data: data.frame(x, y)
     m      s      a      b 
12.423  4.922 11.949 -1.696 
 residual sum-of-squares: 244.6

Number of iterations to convergence: 11 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.947e-06
#---------------------------------
 integrate(function(x){
       11.949*exp(-0.5*((x-12.423)/4.922)^2) -1.696}
       ,6,18)
# 93.96736 with absolute error < 1e-12
```